# Why is tf.abs non-differentiable in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, backpropagation, relu, gradient

I understand why tf.abs is non-differentiable in principle (discontinuity at 0) but the same applies to tf.nn.relu yet, in case of this function gradient is simply set to 0 at 0. Why the same logic is not applied to tf.abs? Whenever I tried to use it in my custom loss implementation TF was throwing errors about missing gradients.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By convention, the $\mathrm{ReLU}$ activation is treated as if it is differentiable at zero (e.g. in [1]). Therefore it makes sense for TensorFlow to adopt this convention for `tf.nn.relu`. As you've found, of course, it's not true in general that we treat the gradient of the absolute value function as zero in the same situation; it makes sense for it to be an explicit choice to use this trick, because it might not be what the code author intends in general.

In a way this is compatible with the Python philosophy that *explicit is better than implicit*. If you mean to use $\mathrm{ReLU}$, it's probably best to use `tf.nn.relu` if it is suitable for your use case.

[1] Vinod Nair and Geoffrey Hinton. *Rectified Linear Units Improve Restricted Boltzmann Machines*. ICML'10 (2010). [URL](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Efritz/absps/reluICML.pdf).

Comment: Thanks a lot. That makes sense. Do you know then what is the easiest way to convert tf.abs into differentiable operation with a gradient at 0 defined as 0?

Comment: @zedsdead Could you just substitute in `tf.nn.relu` in the place you're using `tf.abs`?

Comment: How about `relu(x) + relu(-x)`? :)

Comment: @htl Well, they are not the same thing but NikoNyrh’s answer below is probably the easiest solution.

Answer (score 2):

Creating custom gradient for `tf.abs` may solve the problem:

```
@tf.custom_gradient
def abs_with_grad(x):
  y = tf.abs(x);

  def grad(div): # Derivation intermediate value
    g = 1; # Use 1 to make the chain rule just skip abs
    return div*g;

  return y,grad;
```

Use `1` as above to skip thru' abs or, use the actual abs grad ([Samual K](https://ai.stackexchange.com/users/69830/samuel-k)):

```
g = tf.where(x<0, -1, 1) #now the gradient at 0 would be one. This way u dont have dead  weights.
# With/without:
g = tf.where(x==0, 0, g) #if you realy want the gradient 0 at 0 add  this.
```